# Pohozaev type obstruction for higher order elliptic operators

Tags: ap.analysis-of-pdes, existence-theorems

I was reading about Pohazaev type obstructions: precisely, I mean the following kind of results. Let $h\in C^1(\mathbb{R}^n)$ and consider the following Dirichlet problem
$$
\begin{cases}
\Delta u + hu = |u|^{\frac{4}{n-2}}u &\text{ in }\Omega,\\
u = 0 &\text{ on }\partial\Omega.
\end{cases}
$$
where $\Omega$ is star-shaped (with respect to the origin) smoothy-bounded domain in $\mathbb{R}^n$ with $n\geq 3$. Then, if $h$ satisfies the inequality
$$
h(x) + \frac{1}{2}\langle x,\nabla h(x)\rangle \geq 0,
$$
Pohozaev says that there are no non-trivial solutions for the above boundary value problem.

**Question**. Is there any similar kind of obstruction for higher order elliptic operators?

**Final note**. In the case of higher order operators, we obviously need a better regularity for $h$ but I am just curious to know if there is there some analogous result for higher order, conformally invariant operators.

Comment: https://arxiv.org/pdf/1010.4614.pdf

Comment: Thanks. But I am just curious for ex. say for bi-Laplacian $\Delta^2u$ and say the PDE is $\Delta^2u+hu=|u|^{\frac{8}{n-4}}u$ does $h$ satisfy some similar kind of obstruction like $h(x)+\frac{1}{2}<x,\Delta h(x)>\ \geq 0$ in order to have no solutions?

Comment: Phohozaev identity os about conformal invariance. For operators of order 4 and their associated Yamabe-type equation see (1.5) here https://www.ams.org/journals/era/2004-10-15/S1079-6762-04-00138-6/S1079-6762-04-00138-6.pdf